# synchronous POST with jquery 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to make Web app with IE8 compatibility. The issue I encountered is synchronous POST method.

Since a reason, I've used following code with jquery 3.x

```
console.log("First console log");
$.ajax(
    url: '/Main/SomeUrl',
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: objData,
    success: function (result) {
        'some process after success synchronously'
        console.log("Second console log");
    }
);
```

When I started checking IE version compatibility, above code is work well in other browsers. But in **IE8** with **jQuery 1.7.2** (because of sending file with `jquery.form`, I use 1.7.2), the

```
console.log("First console log")
```

was shown up but

```
console.log("Second console log")
```

was not. This means,I guess, the jQuery's ajax isn't working.

Is there any way to synchronous POST in IE8 with jquery 1.7.2 or javascript code which work in IE8 and Chrome? Thanks for your interesting !

Comment: You are sending json as data. Did you try changing it to JSONP?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what is 'JSONP'... I will find it

Comment: Have check error in console?

Comment: There is no error message in console. So I write console.log where I wonder...

Comment: fyi: JSONP is totally irrelevant. if JSON works in other browsers then the server is not sending JSONP - ignore irrelevant comments

Comment: check developer tools network tab too

Comment: @nipuna777 JSONP doesn't support POST since it is a script request

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is a terrible practice and there is no good reason to ever need it. Open the dev tools and check request status and add some error handling

Comment: ok, I will check dev tool

Comment: The 404 Not Found error occurred

Comment: Doubt that's an IE 8 issue. Inspect the request in dev tools to see what is going on and what path it is using

Comment: @charlietfl I checked the dev tool and look into the request path. But I can't find any strange thing except 404 Not Found error. I think the path is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 does not seem to be fully supporting CORS - http://mcgivery.com/ie8-and-cors/ 
This could be your issue.

You should be able to use this script to fix the issue. https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Simply add the script to your HTML and call the ajax request as you normally would. The plugin should in the background handle all the conversions.

Answer (score 1):

I've got similar problem.
I think to try several ways.

-

1.
Include jQuery of migrate version. When I use this, I've solved some problem in IE of old version.

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"
```

2.
Set up ajax for IE.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                xhr: function() {
                        try{
                            if(window.ActiveXObject)
                                return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch(e) { }

                        return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
            });
```

3.
Set up dataType.

```
$.ajax(
    url: '/Main/SomeUrl',
    method: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: objData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        'some process after success synchronously'
        console.log("Second console log");
    }
);
```

Comment: This isn't work for me... but thank you for your answer!